# Scala + Play: how to pass a parameter into a route in a template?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, templating

I'm tinkering with Scala and Play as a bit of a weekend learning exercise, and one thing that has got me a bit stymied with the templating system is how to pass parameters into routes.

My template looks like this:

```
 @(wallPosts : Array[models.WallPost], wallPostIndex: Integer)

 ...

 <a href="@routes.Application.index(wallPostIndex = @wallPostIndex)">Next</a>

 ...
```

I don't seem to be able to pass @wallPostIndex into the route in this href? How would I go about this?

For reference, this is the route:

```
GET     /    controllers.Application.index(wallPostIndex: Int ?= 1)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing the `@` before the `wallPostIndex` in your href, something like this:

```
<a href="@routes.Application.index(wallPostIndex)">Next</a>
```

Comment: Hiya, I've tried this and then I get nothing in the query string of the link. Any thoughts?

Comment: Additionally, if I use wallPostIndex = 5 as the argument in the route then I do get a ?wallPostIndex=5 query string in the link, so I'm wondering how I replace that 5 with the wallPostIndex parameter initially passed into the template?

Comment: Maybe it's because on your template wallPostIndex is of type `Integer` and the route is waiting for an `Int`. Try changing `Integer` to `Int`, tell me if that works.

Comment: Aaaaah, I think I see the error of my ways. I was confused because I expected the wallPostIndex parameter to appear in the URL even if it matches the default (so the query string isn't necessary).. this solution works. Thanks.